# Prove r is an outer measure $r(A)=\frac{1}{d(A,Y)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove r is  an outer measure $r(A)=\frac{1}{d(A,Y)}$ where Y is y-axis and $d$ is usual metric on $R^2$.
How to prove the condition countable subadditive? I have proved that it satisfied others conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preassume that in this context $r(A)=+\infty\iff d(A,Y)=0$.

Let $A_n\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ and $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$.

Now let us *assume* that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r(A_n)<r(A)\leq+\infty$.

It is enough now to prove that this assumption leads to a contradiction.

If $r(A)<\infty$ then we can find some $a\in A$ with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r(A_n)<r(\{a\})\leq r(A)$.

But from $a\in A$ it follows that $a\in A_n$ for some $n$ and consequently $r(\{a\})\leq r(A_n)$.

On base of this contradiction we conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r(A_n)<r(A)=+\infty$.

$A\cap Y\neq\varnothing$ implies that $A_n\cap Y\neq\varnothing$ for some $n$ hence cannot be true because $r(A_n)<+\infty$.

Combining this with $r(A)=+\infty$ we conclude that a sequence $(a_k)_k$ must exist with $a_k\in A$ for every $k$ and $r(\{a_k\})\to+\infty$.

Let it that $a_k\in A_{n_k}$, so that $r(A_{n_k})\geq r(\{a_k\})$.

Then also $r(A_{n_k})\to+\infty$ contradicting that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r(A_n)<\infty$.

A contradiction is found!

Comment: What is the meaning of "hence cannot be true because $r(A_k)<\infty $"?

Comment: If $A_n\cap Y$ is not empty then some $a$ exists with $a\in A_n\cap Y$ and consequently $d(A_n,Y)=d(a,Y)=0$. Then $r(A_n)=+\infty$ which contradicts the initial assumption (the assumption states that $\sum_n r(A_n)<\infty$ and consequently that $r(A_n)<+\infty$ for every $n$).